# Convert a string to a formula which should allow changing operator precedences

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, string-parsing

So let's say I have a string of a formula (for example `string formula = "(2 + 3 * 3) + 7"`) but I want multiplcation operators to not have order priority over other operators. So in the example above, they would simply solve from left to right except for parentheses which still have priority.

I've been looking all over the net and couldn't find a solution for this. I've found very old StackOverflow threads about it but people in the comments mention the methods are old and dead, and I'm not sure they allow operator precedences changing, they would just treat the string at face value.

I've also found [Flee](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=flee) but no tutorial as to how to use it, and I'm not finding the dll I need to add to my references to implement the framework into my project.

I'm drawing a blank here. Can you guys help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The class that manages to convert the string to the formula is:

```
public class StringToFormula
{
    private string[] _operators = { "-", "+", "/", "*", "^" };
    private Func<double, double, double>[] _operations = {
    (a1, a2) => a1 - a2,
    (a1, a2) => a1 + a2,
    (a1, a2) => a1 / a2,
    (a1, a2) => a1 * a2,
    (a1, a2) => Math.Pow(a1, a2)
    };

    public double Eval(string expression)
    {
        List<string> tokens = getTokens(expression);
        Stack<double> operandStack = new Stack<double>();
        Stack<string> operatorStack = new Stack<string>();
        int tokenIndex = 0;

        while (tokenIndex < tokens.Count)
        {
            string token = tokens[tokenIndex];
            if (token == "(")
            {
                string subExpr = getSubExpression(tokens, ref tokenIndex);
                operandStack.Push(Eval(subExpr));
                continue;
            }
            if (token == ")")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Mis-matched parentheses in expression");
            }
            //If this is an operator  
            if (Array.IndexOf(_operators, token) >= 0)
            {
                while (operatorStack.Count > 0 && Array.IndexOf(_operators, token) < Array.IndexOf(_operators, operatorStack.Peek()))
                {
                    string op = operatorStack.Pop();
                    double arg2 = operandStack.Pop();
                    double arg1 = operandStack.Pop();
                    operandStack.Push(_operations[Array.IndexOf(_operators, op)](arg1, arg2));
                }
                operatorStack.Push(token);
            }
            else
            {
                operandStack.Push(double.Parse(token));
            }
            tokenIndex += 1;
        }

        while (operatorStack.Count > 0)
        {
            string op = operatorStack.Pop();
            double arg2 = operandStack.Pop();
            double arg1 = operandStack.Pop();
            operandStack.Push(_operations[Array.IndexOf(_operators, op)](arg1, arg2));
        }
        return operandStack.Pop();
    }

    private string getSubExpression(List<string> tokens, ref int index)
    {
        StringBuilder subExpr = new StringBuilder();
        int parenlevels = 1;
        index += 1;
        while (index < tokens.Count && parenlevels > 0)
        {
            string token = tokens[index];
            if (tokens[index] == "(")
            {
                parenlevels += 1;
            }

            if (tokens[index] == ")")
            {
                parenlevels -= 1;
            }

            if (parenlevels > 0)
            {
                subExpr.Append(token);
            }

            index += 1;
        }

        if ((parenlevels > 0))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Mis-matched parentheses in expression");
        }
        return subExpr.ToString();
    }

    private List<string> getTokens(string expression)
    {
        string operators = "()^*/+-";
        List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in expression.Replace(" ", string.Empty))
        {
            if (operators.IndexOf(c) >= 0)
            {
                if ((sb.Length > 0))
                {
                    tokens.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Length = 0;
                }
                tokens.Add(c.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        if ((sb.Length > 0))
        {
            tokens.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

The original was [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f62b87d-a35c-4074-a0f0-84a9dd7ff0a5/convert-string-to-formula?forum=csharpgeneral) and I fixed a small bug to be fully functional.

**The Calling example:**

```
        string formula = "(2 + 3 * 3) + 7";
        StringToFormula stf = new StringToFormula();
        double result = stf.Eval(formula);
```

Result is

```
18
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Does that class accepts operator overloading?

Comment: I don't think it accepts operator overloading unfortunately :( In this case there's another way I could reach my goal, does this code decides operator precedence? If so, would there be a way to change the code so multiplication operators don't take order priority over additions and subtractions?